# analytics event tracking not working

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm trying to track image impressions.
So far it looks good, no errors and the debug version of analytics say "top i send everything successful".

Problem is: in my Analytics account nothing appears. :(

My Tracking Code is inserted before `</head>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-47965441-3', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    ga('create', 'UA-47965441-3', 'auto', 'pwAdverts');
</script>
```

Wenn the page is loaded if do this:

```
var allTags = document.getElementsByClassName('pwAdvertAnalyticsTracker');
for (var i = 0, last=allTags.length; i<last; i++) {
    ga_event_tracker.log("sending impression event for " + allTags[i].title);
    ga('pwAdverts.send', 'event', 'Banner', 'Impression', allTags[i].title);
    if (allTags[i].hasAttribute('href')) {
        ga_event_tracker.log("registering click event for " + allTags[i].title);
        ga_event_tracker.addDomListener(allTags[i], 'click', ga_event_tracker.clickEvent);
    }
}
```

I don't get it why in my Account nothing comes up under the Event section. Nothing comes up in the Real-Time-Event section. And nothing comes up one day later...

This is the debugging from analytics:

> Executing Google Analytics commands.
>   Running command: ga("advert.send", "event", "Videos", "play", "Fall Campaign")
>
> Sent beacon:
>   v=1&_v=j40d&a=1171459049&t=event&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxx.de%2Fxxx.php&ul=de&de=windows-1252&sd=24-bit&sr=1280x1024&vp=1265x267&je=1&fl=19.0%20r0&ec=Videos&ea=play&el=Fall%20Campaign&_utma=210528646.892470955.1444392266.1447925984.1447925984.1&_utmz=210528646.1447925984.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)&_utmht=1448005939959&_u=CACCAEABI~&jid=&cid=892470955.1444392266&tid=UA-47965441-3&z=1270254021
>
> _j1              (&jid)
>
> adSenseId        (&a)   1171459049
>
> apiVersion       (&v)   1
>
> clientId         (&cid) 892470955.1444392266
>
> encoding         (&de)  windows-1252
>
> eventAction      (&ea)  play
>
> eventCategory    (&ec)  Videos
>
> eventLabel       (&el)  Fall Campaign
>
> flashVersion     (&fl)  19.0 r0
>
> hitType          (&t)   event
>
> javaEnabled      (&je)  1
>
> language         (&ul)  de
>
> location         (&dl)  http://www.xxx.de/xxx.php
>
> screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
>
> screenResolution (&sr)  1280x1024
>
> trackingId       (&tid) UA-47965441-3
>
> viewportSize     (&vp)  1265x267

Has someone a clue?

Comment: For one thing, you are creating your tracking object twice - one with a name and one without a name. I think the second gets ignored, but you might want to test it.

Comment: I would also double check that you aren't filtering your IP in that analytics view.

Comment: The seccond tracking object make no differenz. I tried it withe the default tracking Object(no name) and with the seccond tracking object(named). Both bring me no results.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was like @GreatBlakes mentioned, there was an IP filter for my IP, but it was very good hidden. Someone setup an Account width IP filter some years ago...